# Can not delete realm object on NavigatorIOS right click action

Tags: ios, react-native, realm, data-persistence

I am trying to add a single sign on feature in a react-native app. I am using realm for data persistence. It is working fine with sign in process and stores data when user is login in fist time. But I want to remove user object from local storage when I click on logout button in navigator top right corner.

[image: home screen]

I am getting an `Invalid arguments` exception when I try to delete user object from realm storage in `onRightButtonPress` event. Here is code for this event in NavigatorIOS.

```
<NavigatorIOS
    barTintColor="#000000"
    tintColor="#fff"
    titleTextColor="#fff"
    ref={(ref) => this._navigator = ref}
    style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor: '#fff'}}
    initialRoute={{
        title: 'NOOZOO',
        component: Home,
        leftButtonIcon: require('../images/menu.png'),
        onLeftButtonPress: () => { this._drawer.open() },
        rightButtonTitle: 'Logout',
        onRightButtonPress: () => {alert('Logout');
                                   console.log({name: global.__user.name,token: global.__user.token});
                                   var users = realm.objects('User');
                                   console.log(users.length);
                                   console.log(users[0].isValid());
                                   realm.write(()=>{
                                    realm.delete('User', users[0]);
                                  });
                                   console.log('deleted');
                                  this._navigate({'title':'Company','routeName':'Home','active':false,'iconUrl': require('../images/check.png'),'newView':false}); 

                                  console.log(users);
                                  },
    }}/>
```

I am printing some values to consoles in order to verify if realm is accessible and have some object in storage, which seems fine as in following image.

[image: Console output when Logout is pressed]

I don't know if I am doing something wrong with realm method call or something. I have seen the docs for realm and also read issue about it on github but was unable to resolve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call do delete does not take the object type as its first argument. Try changing that line to this:

```
realm.delete(users[0]);
```

Comment: this solution worked but I am wondering how realm automatically infer based on object without telling it about collection Class.

Comment: Since the object is created from Realm we can tell what type of object it is and delete it appropriately.

Comment: from your answer, we are not explicitly mentioning the object type is 'User'.

Comment: Exactly. That information is stored internally in each User object returned when accessing elements in the `Results` object `users`